# Laravel getting file content and save to DB when registering

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'country' => 'http://ip-api.com/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'secret_question' => $data['secret_question'],
            'question_answer' => $data['question_answer'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is register function in laravel controller called `AuthController.php`

This line `'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],` works fine, I'm gettig user's IP. 
This http://ip-api.com/json/YOURipADDRESS API which detects not only location but also it detects some more stuff based on IP address. I only need to get `countryCode` from that API and store it to DB. How to do it correctly in this file ?

**EDIT**

This is my function right now but DB country is empty.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user_details = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'country' => $user_details->country,
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'secret_question' => $data['secret_question'],
        'question_answer' => $data['question_answer'],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: What is the output from the IP api?

Comment: @JilsonThomas This is the outputs: `city, country, countryCode` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user_details = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/your-ip-address'))
```

Now you have all details in `$user_details` as json. You can now use it to store to your DB.

```
$user_details->country  //to get country
```

In your `AuthController.php`

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'country' => $this->getCountry($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'secret_question' => $data['secret_question'],
            'question_answer' => $data['question_answer'],
        ]);
    }

protected function getCountry($ip)
{
   return json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/your-ip-address'))->country;
}
```

Comment: But I only need `country`, not all parameters

Comment: Check again. Updated

Comment: I cant use variables in that file. It always expects a function. Is there anyway to do something like this: `'country' => json_decode(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))->country,` ?

Comment: Nevermind. I did it with variable but still the country field is empty in DB

Comment: Also, `dd($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])‌​))` to see if you are getting the correct IP addres..